# Generics behavior differs in JDK 8 and 9

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-9, java-10

The following simple class ([repo](https://github.com/alostale/jdk-issue-generics) to reproduce it):

```
import static org.hamcrest.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import java.util.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestGenerics {
  @Test
  public void thisShouldCompile() {
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    assertThat("List doesn't contain unexpected elements", myList, not(anyOf(hasItem("d"), hasItem("e"), hasItem("f"))));
  }
}
```

Behavior depends on the JDK version:

- Compiles properly in JDK<=8 (tested with 7 and 8)
- Compilation fails using JDK 9+ (tested with 9, 10 and 11 EA)

With the following error:

```
[ERROR] /tmp/jdk-issue-generics/src/test/java/org/alostale/issues/generics/TestGenerics.java:[17,17] no suitable method found for assertThat(java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>,org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? super java.lang.Object>>)
    method org.junit.Assert.<T>assertThat(java.lang.String,T,org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super T>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T has incompatible bounds
        upper bounds: java.lang.String,java.lang.Object
        lower bounds: capture#1 of ? super T?,capture#2 of ? super java.lang.Object,capture#3 of ? super java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,capture#4 of ? super T?)
    method org.junit.Assert.<T>assertThat(T,org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

Is this some expected change in JDK 9 or it's a bug?

I could extract matchers to typed variables in this way, and it would work:

```
    Matcher<Iterable<? super String>> m1 = hasItem("d");
    Matcher<Iterable<? super String>> m2 = hasItem("e");
    Matcher<Iterable<? super String>> m3 = hasItem("f");
    assertThat(myList, not(anyOf(m1, m2, m3)));
```

But still the question is: is it correct `javac` <=8 is being able to infer types, but not in 9+?

Comment: It sure looks like a bug to me. There seem to be many fixes related to compiling generics code in JDK 9: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177097?jql=status%20in%20(Resolved%2C%20Closed%2C%20Completed%2C%20Finalized)%20AND%20resolution%20in%20(Fixed%2C%20Delivered)%20AND%20affectedVersion%20%3D%20%229%22%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%20%229%22%20AND%20component%20%3D%20tools%20AND%20text%20~%20%22generics%22.

Comment: ...and the `Assert` class in the `junit:4.12` is compiled with Java5 (class version 49.0)... if that might lead to any clue either :)

Comment: It would be good if we could track this down to the JLS and ideally a specific change or bug number.

Comment: @tkruse Did you get the public ID?

Comment: Reported to Oracle as https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8206142

Comment: Resolution seems blocked by https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8016196,

Answer (score 12):

After some research I believe we can rule this out as a Junit or hamcrest issue. Indeed, this seems to be a JDK bug. The following code will not compile in JDK > 8:

```
AnyOf<Iterable<? super String>> matcher = CoreMatchers.anyOf(
    CoreMatchers.hasItem("d"), CoreMatchers.hasItem("e"), CoreMatchers.hasItem("f"));
```

> ```
> Error:(23, 63) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
> equality constraints: java.lang.String
> lower bounds: java.lang.Object,java.lang.String
> ```

Turing this into a MCVE which uses no libraries:

```
class Test {
    class A<S> { } class B<S> { } class C<S> { } class D { }

    <T> A<B<? super T>> foo() { return null; }

    <U> C<U> bar(A<U> a1, A<? super U> a2) { return null; }

    C<B<? super D>> c = bar(foo(), foo());
}
```

A similar effect can be achieved using a single variable in `bar` which results in upper bounds equality constraint as opposed to a lower:

```
class Test {
    class A<S> { } class B<S> { } class C<S> { } class D { }

    <T> A<B<? super T>> foo() { return null; }

    <U> C<U> bar(A<? super U> a) { return null; }

    C<B<? super D>> c = bar(foo());
}
```

> ```
> Error:(21, 28) java: incompatible types: inference variable U has incompatible bounds
> equality constraints: com.Test.B<? super com.Test.D>
> upper bounds: com.Test.B<? super capture#1 of ? super com.Test.D>,java.lang.Object
> ```

It looks like when the JDK is attempting to rationalize `? super U` it fails to find the proper wildcard class to use. Even more interesting, if you fully specify the type for `foo`, then the compiler will actually succeed. *This holds true for both MCVE's and the original post*:

```
// This causes compile to succeed even though an IDE will call it redundant
C<B<? super D>> c = bar(this.<D>foo(), this.<D>foo());
```

And just like in the case you presented, Breaking up the execution into multiple lines will produce the correct results:

```
A<B<? super D>> a1 = foo();
A<B<? super D>> a2 = foo();
C<B<? super D>> c = bar(a1, a2);
```

---

Because there are multiple ways to write this code that should be functionally equivalent, and given that only some of them compile, my conclusion is that that this is not the intended behavior of the JDK. There is a bug somewhere within the evaluation of wildcards that have a `super` bound.

My recommendation would be to compile existing code against JDK 8, and for newer code requiring JDK > 8, to fully specify the generic value.

Comment: To be honest, I believe that it was pretty clear to be a bug in the compiler, however it would be interesting to link it to the JLS, to point exactly where the compiler is wrong (or if something changed in the JLS that caused it).

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty for your research, though I think there is more to be done to actually resolve the problem. Let's see what happens on @tkruse's bug report.

Comment: @DidierL thanks for the bounty. I did try to take a look through the type inference section of the JLS specification for differences, but I didn't find anything immediately obvious to indicate the rules for this should be different, and I don't have enough knowledge to validate this code manually by following the JLS rules alone. I do notice that [§18.5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2) has some new sections compared to 8 and specifically there is a note:

Comment: @DidierL Under various special circumstances, based on the bounds appearing in B2, we eagerly resolve an inference variable that appears as the return type of the invocation. This is to avoid unfortunate situations in which the usual constraint, ‹R θ → T›, is not completeness-preserving. It is, unfortunately, possible that by eagerly resolving the variable, we are unable to make use of bounds that would be inferred later.

Answer (score 1):

I created a different MCVE showing a difference in type inference:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class Example {

    public class Matcher<T> {
        private T t;
        public Matcher(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }   
    }

    public <N> Matcher<N> anyOf(Matcher<N> first, Matcher<? super N> second) {
        return first;
    }

    public <T> Matcher<List<? super T>> hasItem1(T item) {
        return new Matcher<>(Arrays.asList(item));
    }

    public <T> Matcher<List<? super T>> hasItem2(T item) {
        return new Matcher<>(Arrays.asList(item));
    }

    public void thisShouldCompile() {
        Matcher x = (Matcher<List<? super String>>) anyOf(hasItem1("d"), hasItem2("e"));
    }
}
```

JDK8 compile passes, JDK10 gives:

```
Example.java:27: error: incompatible types: Example.Matcher<List<? super Object>> cannot be converted to Example.Matcher<List<? super String>>
        Matcher x = (Matcher<List<? super String>>) anyOf(hasItem1("d"), hasItem2("e"));
```

So it seems JDK10 has a bug resolving `N` to `List<? super String>` in

```
Matcher<N> anyOf(Matcher<N> first, Matcher<? super N> second)
```

when calling

```
anyOf(Matcher<List<? super String>>, Matcher<List<? super String>>)
```

I would recommend reporting this issue to OpenJDK (linking the issue here), and possibly reporting the problem to the hamcrest project.