# Why can't java infer this type?

Tags: java, pattern-matching, type-inference

I was trying to mimic some pattern matching behaviour in java:

```java
interface Result<T>
{
    <U> U eliminate(Function<T, U> f, BiFunction<Integer, String, U> g);
}

record Success<T>(T value) implements Result<T>
{
    @Override public <U> U eliminate(Function<T, U> f, BiFunction<Integer, String, U> g)
    {
        return f.apply(value);
    }
}

record Failure<T>(int errCode, String message) implements Result<T>
{
    @Override public <U> U eliminate(Function<T, U> f, BiFunction<Integer, String, U> g)
    {
        return g.apply(errCode, message);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Result<Double> result = Result.success(4.0);

        var log = result.eliminate(
            value -> "Success: " + value,
            (code, message) -> "Failure: " + code + " " + message
        );

        System.out.println(log);
    }
}
```

The above would compile and run to output "Success: 4.0".
However when omitted the intermediate variable `log` and directly `println` its definition,
unless explicitly stating the return type of `eliminate` i.e. `result.<String>eliminate(...)`,
java would suddenly not know what to do:

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Result<Double> result = Result.success(4.0);

        System.out.println(result.eliminate(
            value -> "Success: " + value,
            (code, message) -> "Failure: " + code + " " + message
        ));
    }
}
```

```
% javac -Xdiags:verbose Main.java
Main.java:7: error: reference to println is ambiguous
        System.out.println(result.eliminate(
                  ^
  both method println(char[]) in PrintStream and method println(String) in PrintStream match
Main.java:7: error: method println in class PrintStream cannot be applied to given types;
        System.out.println(result.eliminate(
                          ^
  required: char[]
  found:    String
  reason: argument mismatch; inference variable U has incompatible bounds
      upper bounds: char[],Object
      lower bounds: String
  where U,T are type-variables:
    U extends Object declared in method <U>eliminate(Function<T,U>,BiFunction<Integer,String,U>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Result
2 errors
```

Edit: definition of `Result.success`

```java
static <T> Result<T> success(T value) { return new Success<>(value); }
```

Comment: Which Java version are you using? In Java 20 (openjdk 20.0.2) this seems to work fine.

Comment: @majusebetter openjdk 21 2023-09-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21+35-2513)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21+35-2513, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: This might be a bug. Older versions had issues as well, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928300/generics-behavior-differs-in-jdk-8-and-9

Comment: @majusebetter The code doesn't compile on Java 20 either. I think this is intended behaviour. The type inference and overload resolution algorithm is just not strong enough to deal with this combination of "no most specific method" + "poly expressions" + "implicitly typed lambda".

Comment: @Sweeper Is it also intended for declared vars to be inferred while not when used as a argument?

Comment: @Futarimiti Yes. `println` has a lot of overloads, so a lot of target types need to be checked to determine the invocation type. In particular, `String` and `char[]` are both compatible because there are no bounds on `U`, but only later down the algorithm does it find that `char[]` doesn't actually work.

Comment: @Sweeper Why would `char[]` be inferred though? Isn't the argument clearly a string?

Comment: Because the call to `eliminate` is a poly expression. The type of the call cannot be determined just by looking at the call itself. It has to look at the *target type* (i.e. whatever type `println` expects). The idea is, by looking at that, a "better" return type for `eliminate` might be deduced (of course, we humans know that is not true in this case).

Comment: @Sweeper Strange behavior. In Eclipse it *does* actually compile and run with openjdk 20 as mentioned above, but not on the shell.

Comment: @Sweeper https://majusebetter.de/eclipse.webm

Comment: @majusebetter The Eclipse compiler behaves differently from javac in a lot of ways ([a recent example I encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77992722/5133585)), so it's not that surprising. But from reading the JLS, i don't see how this can compile.

Answer (score -1):

Since you seem to be returning the 'U' type. I'd switch out your 'type' and make it

```
interface Result<U>

record Success<U>(U value) implements Result<U>
```

Or just make it `String` since that's exactly what you're looking to return.

Also, from a readability perspective, I'd create a 'Response' class that maps the value to message.  If you're using Spring, you could use a `ResponseEnity`.  It makes it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but this is not really an answer to my question.

Comment: It kind of is...

Comment: @Dan The question just happens to use an example where a Number was used to represent both `T` and `U`. But theoretically, someone could put in a wildly different type for `T`, like a `String`. Futarimiti is correct, your solution breaks the original program's functionality and forces the return and input types to be the same.